# How to tell unicorn shell script in rails application to use specific ruby and gemset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shell, ruby-on-rails-4, unicorn

How do I set up unicorn shell file to use ruby-2.1.2@my_gemset so that it can run as `sudo service unicorn start`. My Rails Application config folder contain `unicorn.sh` file which has the following content.

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          unicorn
# Required-Start:    $remote_fs $syslog
# Required-Stop:     $remote_fs $syslog
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5
# Default-Stop:      0 1 6
# Short-Description: Manage unicorn server
# Description:       Start, stop, restart unicorn server for a specific application.
### END INIT INFO
set -e

# Feel free to change any of the following variables for your app:
TIMEOUT=${TIMEOUT-90}
APP_ROOT=/home/user/Documents/workspace/MyApp
PID=$APP_ROOT/tmp/pids/unicorn.pid
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT;bundle exec bin/unicorn -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E development"
AS_USER="www-data"
action="$1"
set -u

OLD_BIN="$PID.oldbin"

sig () {
  test -s "$PID" && kill -$1 `cat $PID`
}

oldsig () {
  test -s $OLD_BIN && kill -$1 `cat $OLD_BIN`
}

run () {
  if [ "$(id -un)" = "$AS_USER" ]; then
    eval $1
  else
    su -c "$1" - $AS_USER
  fi
}

case "$1" in
start)
  sig 0 && echo >&2 "Already running" && exit 0
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
stop)
  sig QUIT && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
force-stop)
  sig TERM && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Not running"
  ;;
restart|reload)
  sig HUP && echo reloaded OK && exit 0
  echo >&2 "Couldn't reload, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
upgrade)
  if sig USR2 && sleep 3
  then
    n=$TIMEOUT
    while test -s $OLD_BIN && test $n -ge 0
    do
      printf '.' && sleep 1 && n=$(( $n - 1 ))
    done
    echo

    if test $n -lt 0 && test -s $OLD_BIN
    then
      echo >&2 "$OLD_BIN still exists after $TIMEOUT seconds"
      exit 1
    fi
    exit 0
  fi
  echo >&2 "Couldn't upgrade, starting '$CMD' instead"
  run "$CMD"
  ;;
reopen-logs)
  sig USR1
  ;;
*)
  echo >&2 "Usage: $0 <start|stop|restart|upgrade|force-stop|reopen-logs>"
  exit 1
  ;;
esac
```

but when i run `sudo service unicorn start` I got this error

```
/var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/bundler-1.5.3/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:220: warning: Insecure world writable dir /usr/local/bin in PATH, mode 040777
Could not find rake-10.4.2 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

But actually i am using `ruby-2.1.2@my_gemset`. How do I tell shell script to use this gemset using rvm.

My `bin/unicorn` file has this content

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
#
# This file was generated by Bundler.
#
# The application 'unicorn' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'pathname'
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile",
  Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

load Gem.bin_path('unicorn', 'unicorn')
```

I know i have to change the path of /usr/bin/env ruby to my ruby but don't know how to do this. Also please let me know how can I set up unicorn shell script to use specific gemset with specific ruby.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `rvm` in my remote server to manage my gems. I've committed the **.ruby-gemset**, and **.ruby-version** so that it's uniform. In my deployment script, I added the snippet below to make sure I'm running the command in the right folder with the correct set of gems. So execute:

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm; cd #{current_path}; /etc/init.d/unicorn #{command}"
```

I'm pretty sure this can be refactored further but I haven't gotten around to updating my script for a while. But so far, it's been working. I'm using `Capistrano` 3.

Comment: source command is not available in unicorn shell script if using `#!/bin/sh`

Comment: Can you try removing the source part and just cd into the directory? That should be sufficient for it to use the correct gemset. You can try to check whether it's using the correct one by doing ```rvm gemset list```. That's what I did last time.

Comment: sorry-removed my comment

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done this before but i think this will work -

Add this line -

```
CMD_TO_USE_GEMSET="cd $APP_ROOT; rvm use ruby-2.1.2@my_gemset"
```

after

```
CMD="cd $APP_ROOT;bundle exec bin/unicorn -c $APP_ROOT/config/unicorn.rb -E development"
```

in your `unicorn.sh`.

And write this in `"start"` and `"restart|reload"` section of your unicorn.sh after `run "$CMD"` -

```
run "$CMD_TO_USE_GEMSET"
```

and now run the command to restart unicorn -

```
sudo service unicorn start
```

Comment: I tried it but I got rvm not found error [prashant](http://stackoverflow.com/users/4061698/prashant)

Comment: Make sure rvm is installed. you can check it by issuing the following command `rvm -v`.

Comment: Actually rvm is already installed but unicorn script file is not picking up rvm command neither I am able reload rvm in shell script. Also `source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm;` is not working in app root

Comment: Put this in your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc : [[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" So you don't have to manually type it for every session. And yes it is needed if you want to use rvm. I think this will fix the issue

Comment: If this doesn't solve your problem. Please reinstall rvm by removing it completely. by following the proper steps.